# Empty Body in Vapor Client GET Response

Tags: swift3, vapor

I'm trying to connect to 
[Bamboo HR's API](https://www.bamboohr.com/api/documentation/), and I've managed to make this work with `curl` and Swift Foundation's `URLRequest`/`URLSession` (as well as an older Express node.js app).

However, when trying to utilize [Vapor's client](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/http/client.html) with the `.get()` method, I'm getting a successful `200` response from BambooHR - but the response's `.body` is empty.

Here's the code snippet:

*key and {myDomain} are placeholders in the example*

```
let encodedKey = "\(key):x".utf8.base64String
let directoryRootUrl = "https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/{myDomain}/v1/employees/directory"

let response = try drop.client.get(
    directoryRootURL,
    headers: [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic \(encodedKey)",
        "Host": "api.bamboohr.com"
    ])
```

When I do `print(response)`, this is what's displayed:

```
Response
- HTTP/1.0 200 OK
- Headers:
    Connection: close
    Vary: User-Agent
    Server: Apache
    Content-Security-Policy:  {...}
    Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2017 00:26:31 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
- Body:
```

I'm wondering if I'm doing anything wrong with Vapor, or if it's a bug.

Comment: I'm seeing this when attempting to communicate with my Philips Hue bridge. Same thing on a POST request on the bridge too. However if I do a GET to google.com, it works. I haven't opened an issue for this as I thought it might be confined to just that hardware but your issue seems to be the same.

Comment: After creating your Droplet, try setting `drop.client = FoundationClient.self`. This version of the client is sometimes better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [tobygriffin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667915/empty-body-in-vapor-client-get-response#comment70534824_41667915) suggested, setting:

```
drop.client = FoundationClient.self
```

after creating the `Droplet` worked.